# My class that implements IEnumerator and IEnumerable doesn't go to foreach statement

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have a class that stores a string list, I would like to make this class usable in a foreach statement, so I found these two interfaces and I tried to implement them.

```
public class GroupCollection : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
{
    public List<string> Groups { get; set; }
    public int Count { get { return Groups.Count; } }
    int position = -1;
}

public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return (IEnumerator)this;
}

public object Current
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return new Group(Groups[position]);
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}

public bool MoveNext()
{
    position++;
    return position < Groups.Count;
}

public void Reset()
{
    position = 0;
}
```

I'm iterating through a GroupCollection variable twice:

```
foreach (GroupCollection.Group in groups) // where groups is a GroupCollection
{
}

foreach (GroupCollection.Group in groups)
{
}

// where Group is a nested class in GroupCollection.
```

When it is at the first foreach it works well (count is 1 at this time). I don't modify anything, and when it goes to the second foreach it doesn't go into the loop. I went through the code line by line in debugging mode and found out that the reset is not called after the first foreach. So should I manually call reset after the foreach? Isn't there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: Having a class implement *both* is a bug.  An enumerator needs to keep track of its current position by itself.  Nobody is setting *position* back to 0 in your code either, the basic reason why it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: I notice that you are returning a new Group with each call to `Current`.  Is that a valid expectation for your use case?  In general, callers would expect that the results of iterating a collection twice would result in the same outputs. If `Group` is something like an immutable value type where different instances can be considered the same, then probably not an issue.

Comment: @SteveMitcham yes, this is intended use. Groups are created dynamically, with folder paths, userlist who could access it, and things like that) and I find this the most proper solution for the problem. And from the source code here, of course, I excluded a lot of unnecessary code). Thank you for noticing it though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I don't modify anything

Yes you do - your `MoveNext()` modifies the state of the class. This is why you shouldn't implement both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` in the same class. (The C# compiler does for iterator blocks, but that's a special case.) You should be able to call `GetEnumerator()` twice and get two entirely independent iterators. For example:

```
foreach (var x in collection)
{
    foreach (var y in collection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", x, y);
    }
}
```

... should give you all possible pairs of items in a collection. But that *only* works when the iterators are independent.

> I went through the code line by line in debugging mode and found out that the reset is not called after the first foreach.

Why would you expect it to? I don't believe the specification says anything about `foreach` calling `Reset` - and that's a good job, as many implementations don't *really* implement it (they throw an exception instead).

Basically, you should make your `GetEnumerator()` method return a new object which keeps the mutable state of the "cursor" over your data. Note that the simplest way of implementing an iterator in C# is *usually* to use an iterator block (`yield return` etc).

I'd also *strongly* encourage you to implement the generic interfaces rather than just the non-generic ones; that way your type can be used much more easily in LINQ code, the iterator variable in a `foreach` statement can be implicitly typed appropriately, etc.

Comment: Do you know why I like your answers? They're not just correct answers. They teach! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Reset` is not called at the end of a `foreach` loop - you *could* do that in the `GetEnumerator` call, or just return the enumerator for the `List`:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return Groups.GetEnumerator;
}
```

Note that with the `yield` keyword there is almost no need to implement `IEnumerator` or `IEnumerable` explicitly:

```
public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
{
    foreach(string s in Groups)
        yield return s;
}
```

Comment: Not quite - the OP is creating a copy of the `Group` in `Current`, so that might not behave in the same way.